# VRF v2 for makeing randomnes number

Tags: chainlink, vrf, chainlink-vrf

I am trying to write a contract that generates a randomness number for some users who are going to mine (digging) in my game, and by chance one of them may find the random number and mine it and win the prize. Still, I don't know if VFR is a good solution, because I think it may be open for others to see the random number I generated, and somehow they write a script and mine that position to win. can you help me to find a better solution or if I am wrong tell me please.

Comment: I think Chainlink Oracle is the best way for you

Comment: are the random numbers shown to the public? I mean the security part for not someone find it and mining it with a script.

Comment: The reason why we use VRF is security, when a random number is generated onchain, it can be seen, so we have to generate it in off chain such a way that VRF solves this problem, you can be sure chainlink method is secure

Comment: I realy appreciate your help. Thanks. If you can mention any links or docs which I can see in a direction of your word I would appreciate it if you tell me.

Comment: Sure, Chainlink has a complete document for it  : https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/getting-started